# Ruby on Rails Solving a No method Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging

I'm currently going through Hartl's Ruby on Rails tutorial and I've come to a roadbloack with a failing test that I don't know how to get to pass. All of the previous tests through chapter 11 have ran correctly so I was hoping some one could help me interpret the errors.

Running:

```
bundle exec rake test
```

Gives me this

```
45 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 45 errors, 0 skips
```

The first six errors are similar to this:

```
1) Error:
MicropostTest#test_should_be_valid:
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError
```

And the rest of the errors follow this pattern:

```
7) Error:
UsersEditTest#test_unsuccessful_edit:
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError


Error:
UsersEditTest#test_unsuccessful_edit:
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

I'm not sure what an undefined method for a nil class would mean. If I need to post any more of my code/errors please let me know. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Edit:

users_controller_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  def setup
    @user = users(:michael)
    @other_user = users(:archer)
  end

  test "should redirect index when not logged in" do
    get :index
    assert_redirected_to login_url
  end

  test "should get new" do
    get :new
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should redirect edit when not logged in" do
    get :edit, id: @user
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to login_url
  end

  test "should redirect update when not logged in" do
    patch :update, id: @user, user: { name: @user.name, email: @user.email }
    assert_not flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to login_url
  end

  test "should redirect edit when logged in as wrong user" do
    log_in_as(@other_user)
    get :edit, id: @user
    assert flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to root_url
  end

  test "should redirect update when logged in as wrong user" do
    log_in_as(@other_user)
    patch :update, id: @user, user: { name: @user.name, email: @user.email }
    assert flash.empty?
    assert_redirected_to root_url
  end

  test "should redirect destroy when not logged in" do
    assert_no_difference 'User.count' do
      delete :destroy, id: @user
    end
    assert_redirected_to login_url
  end

  test "should redirect destroy when logged in as a non-admin" do
    log_in_as(@other_user)
    assert_no_difference 'User.count' do
      delete :destroy, id: @user
    end
    assert_redirected_to root_url
  end
end
```

micropost.rb

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }
end
```

Comment: It means that something is `nil` and you're calling `each` on it.

Comment: So yes, obviously we won't be able to help you unless you post the code of the test in question. Anyway, I don't see why you would need an `each` for a user edit test...?

Comment: The 45 errors are the same two issues that affect every test I have in my program so I'm assuming it has to do with something that all of the tests use. I'll edit my post with some code that may be relevant.